# Generating a list to store input data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that keeps tab of the score of a card game and by the completion of the game generates a table with names of players, points and total profit/loss. I need some advice on how to execute one crucial aspect of scoring keeping for this project and hence I'll start by giving you the main lines of code of the project:

---

```
# takes player information//

player_number = int(input('number of players:'))

cards_per_player = int(input('cards per player:'))

# takes player data and generates dictionary

player_dict = {}

for x in range(1,player_number+1):

    player_dict["player{0}".format(x)] = input('name of player:')



print (player_dict)

# takes the dictionary values and creates a list 

players_keys = list(player_dict.values())

# function that takes an input for the 'hands' won for each round for each player in the game...maximum hands for each player are 3 and minimum are 0. 

def round():

        counter_for_round = []

        for i in range(0,(len(players_keys))):

                score_per_player = int((input(str(players_keys[i])+':')))

                counter_for_round.append(score_per_player)`
```

The `counter_for_round` variable stores data on each player's count of hands for any particular round. For example, if the total number of players were three, the list would look like: [1,1,0] or [3,0,0] or [2,1,0] and etc etc. Now, what I want it is to generate variables with empty lists for each item within the list 'players_keys'. So, for example, if `players_keys = [a,b,c]`, I want to generate three variables, a b and c, which are empty lists in order for me to store the total scores within them for each player.

How do I go about this? Also, I know that this method can be quite detrimental and hence I am curious as to whether you can think of a simpler way to execute this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you dont know how many players there are, you shouldnt try to create "new variables" for each player, but use a dictionary instead like you already did with `player_dict`.

So your result would be `score = {key: list() for key in players_keys}`, which is a dictionary with every player name as a key and an empty list as a value.

Also i'm not sure why you even need `player_dict` since the new `score` variable would include all important information. So maybe merging input of player names and list creation would be better.

```
# takes player data and generates dictionary
player_dict = dict()
for x in range(0, player_number):
    player_name = input('name of player:')
    player_dict[player_name] = list()

# takes the dictionary values and creates a list
players_keys = list(player_dict.keys())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! Although I have one confusion still: How do I call the particular item from my round function and process its value to the appropriate key in my dictionary? For instance, if my function yields an input result of a = 0, b= 1 and c=1, how should I add these values to my empty lists outside the function without referring to their index? The number of players, names of players and hence the whole structure remains heavily unknown to me and hence I’m not sure how to transfer one value to another without any indexing.

Comment: Inside of round, instead of iterating over `range(0,(len(players_keys)))`, you iterate with `for name in players_keys` and than you can add the input score to `player_dict[name]`